# set datepicker value automatically based on previous datepicker in angular(setvalue)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5, angular9

I have two datepickers **picker1** and **picker2**. What I am trying to to is that when I select a date in **picker1** the **picker2** should automatically get selected and the date in the **picker2** should be 60 days from date in **picker1**

For example if its march 1 2021 in **picker1** It should be april 29 2021 in **picker2**

I have searched for various solutions in stackoverflow but couldn't get the exact solution.
Pleease help if u guys know

**Datepicker1:**

```
                       <td>
                          <mat-form-field >
                            <input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker1" formControlName="startdate" 
                            (dateChange)="setDate($event.value)"placeholder="Start Date">
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
```

**Datepicker2**

```
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="enddate" 
                              placeholder="End Date">
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
```

**My ts**

```
    setDate(a) {
            this.datecheck = this.eventaddform.value.startdate+60
this.eventaddform.patchValue({
          expirydate: this.datecheck
    
    
        })
       }
```

I have created a sample stackblitz justincase if u guys need something to work with

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-picker-sample-fr-h19bes?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dateChange` event from `picker1` to set `picker2` by binding `value`

I've created a basic stackblitz example removing `Forms`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-picker-sample-fr-kwcxta?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

PS: adding 60 to March 01 2021 gave me April 30 2021. So you can try adding `59`